# Pass multiple json objects throught ajax to razor pages

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to pass multiple parameters using ajax 'data:'. In cs file parameter model is null.
What am I doing wrong here? I've tried with and without JSON.stringify

this is in chtml razor page.

```
var Obj_A = [];
var obj = {};
var inputs = $("#fieldset1 input[name^=show_all_]");
                for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
                    var text_id = $(inputs[i]).attr("id").replace('show_all_','');
                    var value = $(inputs[i]).val();
                    obj[text_id]=value;
                }
Obj_A.push(obj);
```

.
.
same for Obj_B
.

```
var model = {
            Item_1: Obj_A ,
            Item_2: Obj_B 
        };
$("#btn_insert").click(function () {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/Edit?handler=Import",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(model),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (response) {
                
            },
            error: function (e) {
                
            }
        });
        });
```

console.log for model has values.

this is in chtml.cs razor page.

```
public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostImport([FromBody]All_Obj model)
        {
            {
                return new JsonResult(new { message = "2", filename = "1" });
            }
        }
```

model parameter is always null.

model class

```
public class model
    {
        public Item_1 field_1 { get; set; }
        public Item_2 field_2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Item_1 class

```
public class Item_1
    {
        public string field_item_1_1 { get; set; }
        public string field_item_1_2 { get; set; }
        public string field_item_1_3 { get; set; }
}
```

Item_2 class

```
public class Item_2
    {
        public string field_item_2_1 { get; set; }
        public string field_item_2_2 { get; set; }
        public string field_item_2_3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: also show your model class

Comment: Ehsan Sajjad I have update the question.

Comment: try updating your model like : `public class model
    {
        public Item_1 field_1 { get; set; }
        public Item_2 field_2 { get; set; }

        public model()
        {
            field_1  = new Item_1();
            field_2  = new Item_2();
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code to add data to model:

```
var Obj_A = {};
Obj_A.field_item_1_1=$("#show_all_field_item_1_1").val();
Obj_A.field_item_1_2=$("#show_all_field_item_1_2").val();
Obj_A.field_item_1_3=$("#show_all_field_item_1_3").val();
var Obj_B = {};
Obj_B.field_item_2_1=$("#show_all_field_item_2_1").val();
Obj_B.field_item_2_2=$("#show_all_field_item_2_2").val();
Obj_B.field_item_2_3=$("#show_all_field_item_2_3").val();
```

So that the model structure will be like this:
[image]

Comment: I finally solve the problem. The idea comes from Ehsan Sajjad response.
What i have change.
inside model class


public class model
    {
         public Item_1[] field_1 { get; set; }
        public Item_2[] field_2 { get; set; }
    }


and in cs insted of All_Obj to model

public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostImport([FromBody]model model)
        {
            {
                return new JsonResult(new { message = "2", filename = "1" });
            }
        }